# Enable Hyper-V and Hardware Virtialization for VirtualBOX under Windows

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I am developing [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) apps under windows.

I want to regularly run the app under:

1. Windows Phone Emulator
2. iPhone Emulator

For the first, Hyper-V needs to enabled under windows.

For the second, one needs an OSX to connect to. I am trying to run OSX under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). For this to work, Hardware Virtualization needs to be enabled.

Now, when I enable Hyper-V VirtualBox does not detect the hardware virtualization. And according to [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12350), that will not change.

Is there an solution how I can test iOS and WindowsPhone without having to enable/disable Hyper-V (which requires a restart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualbox 6 can use Hyper-V as backend virtualization engine. So that you can use them at same time.

You can enable this feature by this command:

```
cmd
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0
```

According to this:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/hyperv-support.html

This is an experimental feature.
So this feature could be unstable and doesn't even work.

At least it work on my laptop.
[Screenshot that Vbox and HyperV at same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V9zv.png)

Comment: you can also add the line `<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" value="0"/>` to your `?:\Users\%USERNAME%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` ([source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853&start=120#p454358)). Make sure you're editing the config file when VirtualBox isn't running (otherwise your changes will be lost when the app exits).

Answer (score 5):

I understand your pain-point, but this is just not possible to attain w/o a system restart because of the simple fact that the virtualization technologies you mentioned here are of different types.

In your case, Hyper-V that you use for #1 is a "Type 1" hyper-visor which run on host machine hardware. Other examples in this category include Citrix XenServer and VmWare ESXi.
The Virtual Box that you use for #2 is a "Type 2" hosted hyper-visor which runs within an OS.

If you need to toggle b/w these, a restart is eminent AFAIK.

A quick way to see the mode is by running "bcdedit" from Command Prompt to see the current config.
1. To disable Hyper-V run:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

2. To turn Hyper-V back on run:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

However, you would need to reboot in both the cases. I just mentioned a easy config way to make you understand what was happening in the boot loader when toggling between the Type 1 and Type 2 hyper-visor modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via opening powershell in administrator mode and run the following code :

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`